# Using Apache mod_proxy to reverse proxy and change url

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I am successfully using Apache mod_proxy to reverse proxy a request to testing.com/foo/bar to mybackendservice.com/foo. However, instead of the current url which is shown in the browser : testing.com/foo/bar, I would like to have the url reflect testing.com/foo. How can I achieve this? My mod proxy setup looks something like:

```
ProxyPass /foo/bar mybackendservice.com/foo
ProxyPassReverse /foo/bar mybackendservice.com/foo
```

I did also try rewriting the url using:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule foo/bar foo [NC]
```

but this doesn't seeem to work. Is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTTP redirects instead of mod_rewrite.

Create a script which returns HTTP status 302 Found and specify HTTP Header Location: /foo